# Average with a condition Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, average

I have the data in the follow way from Oracle database:

```
check          HR       Serie       Name
14:00:31    13:59:19    6120        A
14:10:31    13:59:21    6120        A
14:00:31    13:57:19    6120        A
14:04:01    14:02:00    6120        B
14:06:01    14:02:14    6120        B
14:04:01    14:04:00    6120        B
14:04:01    14:02:00    7100        A
14:08:01    14:03:00    7100        A
14:04:01    14:04:00    7100        A
```

I want to calculate the average of the column 'HR' for each serie and name (both), **but if only the value of column check  is the same**.

The result would be:

```
check        AVG(HR)    Serie       Name
14:00:31    13:58:19    6120        A
14:00:31    14:03:00    6120        B
14:04:01    14:03:00    7100        A
```

Here's my code:

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SysDate) + (AVG(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(HR, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'SSSSS')) / 60)) / 24 / 60, 'hh24:mi:ss'), Serie,Name 
from table 
group by Serie, name
```

the problem, I calculate the average even if the value column check is different

Comment: So you're saying that you want the calculations to group by the `check` also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `check` in the `GROUP BY` clause and add a `HAVING` clause that will check for duplicates:

```
SELECT check,
       TO_CHAR( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + AVG( HR - TRUNC( HR ) ), 'HH24:MI:SS' )
         AS "AVG(HR)",
       serie,
       name
GROUP BY check, serie, name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: can you please check my last question please :/

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answer but is it possible to identifie the duplicate because for each series and name i have 4 result and in final i want to have result:

```
check          HR       Serie       Name
14:00:31    13:58:19    6120        A
14:12:31    14:03:00    6120        B
14:10:31    13:59:21    6120        A (duplicate)
14:04:01    14:03:00    6120        B (duplicate)
```

and after having the same result but the duplicates ? And @MTO i didn't undestant why you add having count (*) >1 what is the difference  if you add it ?